# Align div with fixed position on the right side

Tags: javascript, css

I want to show a `div` which is always visible even as the user scrolls the page. I have used the CSS `position: fixed;` for that.

Now I also want to show the `div` at the right hand corner of the parent `div`.

I tried to use this CSS code to achieve the goal:

```css
.test {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: right;
}
```

But it doesn't align the element on the right side.

My example page can be found [here](https://nvoids.com/width.jsp), the `div` element I want to align is called `test` under the parent class `parent`.

Is there any CSS or JavaScript solution to aligning the fixed position element on the right side of the screen?

Comment: try float : right in your class

Comment: So you want the word "Another Test" to appear in the top right corner of the grey box and for the grey box to remain in place when the user scrolls?

Comment: no the div "test" with text Another Test to be aligned right to the parent div that is "parent" and the div "test" to remain in place as the user scrolls...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With position fixed, you need to provide values to set where the div will be placed,
since it's a *fixed* position.

Something like....

```
.test
{
   position:fixed;
   left:100px;
   top:150px;
}
```

**Fixed** - Generates an absolutely positioned element, positioned relative to the browser window. The element's position is specified with the "left", "top", "right", and "bottom" properties

More on position [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Comment: "Generates an absolutely positioned element" - perhaps a rephrasing is in order, since "absolute positioning" is another distinct concept?

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen - Perhaps discuss that with the author at w3c then.

Comment: i found a solution with using only left:400px; no need of using the top and bottom... but i should say... not a complete solution for a complex problem. either w3c or the browser guys should set a high standard for ui with css

Comment: @Pradyut Bhattacharya - I don't see what the problem is, you have a fixed position set for the `<div>`. You need to supply the position it should live at, if you don't its going to sit at the default position. If you don't want that functionality, then I suggest you choose another type of positioning so `text-align: right` works, but you chose fixed so you have to define some values.

Comment: @gmcalab how about that i want the postion:fixed as i want the div to be visible as the user scrolls and the div to be aligned right and i m changing the text of the parent div with javascript and and the parent div's width changes to less than 200px.. ha ha a complicated question... but you don't have a answer now...

Comment: @gmcalab - Dude, you linked to w3schools not w3c ;) There's kind of a big difference.

Comment: the question was about "right with position fixed", thus using a left: is not the solution here.

Comment: The question was solved and selected as answer almost two years ago, thus making your observation useless.

Comment: This is the incorrect answer. See below for the answer describing the right:x style attribute.

Answer (score 52):

You can use two imbricated div. But you need a fixed width for your content, that's the only limitation.

```
<div style='float:right; width: 180px;'>
 <div style='position: fixed'>
   <!-- Your content -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so glad i found this answer.. didn't think there was a css solution for this.  looks like i just needed the "fixed" element to be inside another div the whole time.

Comment: great answer - + 1 for the word imbricated

Answer (score 46):

Use the 'right' attribute alongside fixed position styling. The value provided acts as an offset from the right of the window boundary.

Code example:

```css
.test {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
```

If you need some padding you can set `right` property with a certain value, for example: `right: 10px`.

Note: `float` property doesn't work for position `fixed` and `absolute`

Answer (score 8):

Trying to do the same thing. If you want it to be aligned on the right side then set the value of `right` to `0`. In case you need some padding from the right, set the value to the size of the padding you need.

Example:

```css
.test {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px; /* Padding from the right side */
}
```

Comment: There is indeed no need to use a nested div (although that works too).

Comment: Hmm... This didn't place the div at the right hand corner of the parent div but right relative to the html-element, ie alight right to the full width of page. So a nested approach seems necessary. Missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the real solution (with other cool CSS3 stuff):

```css
#fixed-square {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9500;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Note the *top:0* and *right:0*.  That's what did it for me.

Comment: I don't know why they vote you down but your solution solve my problem.

Comment: @AsmeJust Most likely because of the insane amount of overhead in his code. The solution is supposed to be around 3 to 5 lines, He adds in a lot of extra, unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score 1):

make a parent div, in css make it float:right
then make the child div's position fixed
this will make the div stay in its position at all times and on the right

Answer (score 1):

I use this to put a div (with its stuff inside) at the bottom-right of the page with some margin:

```
.my-div-container{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1rem;
    left: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is to give the element a left margin . The elements below it in left margin will be ckickable

```css
#my_id{
      margin-left: 75%;
      position:fixed;
      right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="my_id" >
    My Text
  </div>
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do this. It doesn't affect the horizontal position.

```
.test {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 }
```