# Align fixed div to top right of variable width TD

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-table

I've got a project where I need to top-right align a div so that it sits on top of an existing variable-width td.

What has me stumped is the variable width aspect.  I can get the div to sit on top of the existing relatively positioned td by using fixed positioning for the div.  However, because the TD width can change I can't set a "left:" value for the div.

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate it with left aligned in the td, now I just need to get it to right align:

```
jsfiddle.net/ErDr6/36/
```

I've looked at some other posts, but they seem to deal with fixed width elements:

[Align div with fixed position on the right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829665/align-div-right-with-position-fixed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, change `position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;` so that the arrows won't stay fixed relative to the viewport when the page scrolls. Then, add the following:

```
#col_arrow {
    right: 0;
}
.wc-day-column-header {
    position: relative;
}
```

That will align the arrow to the right of its parent. We add `position: relative;` to the parent to restrict it to that container.

Comment: Oops, yes position: absolute makes a lot more sense.  Thanks.  Unfortunately when I add right:0; it aligns the arrow to the right of the viewport rather than to the right of the td : http://jsfiddle.net/TYGs9/1/

Comment: Interesting.  What browser is that in?  Mac firefox and safari are both displaying the arrow at the far-right of the viewport for me.

Comment: Chrome, which is the same webkit engine that Safari uses. What do you get with this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/sl1dr/4GC6d/

Comment: That is very, very strange. I can't explain that behaviour as the CSS is correct. There must be something else playing up. It's also strange that it works fine for me.

Comment: You can't use `position:absolute` in table cells in Firefox (so no doubt other browsers). You need to assign a div with the `position:relative` and then place the absolute div within that -> http://jsfiddle.net/TYGs9/2/

Comment: Thanks, that div with the relative positioning fixes it for me.  Much thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be dynamic then absolute position can be calculated as:

theTD.offsetLeft+theTD.offsetWidth-arrow.offsetWidth

Comment: So, do it as a jquery statement instead of css?

Comment: yes. Based on the fiddle it looks like you move the arrow with the mouseover. so one arrow that repositions on mouseover as opposed to having to apply a style to every cell.

Comment: OK, maybe that is the way I should go.  Had been hoping to figure out the CSS way to improve my CSS chops :)  But I can definitely do in jquery.  I have to set the height that way as far as I know so it would make sense.